# Declarative approach to constrain data ranges in table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-range

I would like to learn a declarative approach for a data constraint issue I have had from time to time related to exclusive date ranges.

Below is a simplified example. I have items and prices on those items. I want the effective date range of the prices to be mutually exclusive with no overlap.

As I understand things with Oracle, [user-defined functions are not eligible for use in `CONSTRAINT` declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_constraints.htm#ADFNS282) - and I can't even imagine how poorly it would perform if it were allowed. So I require a procedural approach using triggers. Typical trigger source is also included below.

I am not interested in learning better procedural logic for use within the trigger (it is just a simple demonstrative example). I am interested in learning a more declarative solution to a relatively popular data constraint issue I (and likely others) face.

I want to eliminate trigger-based solutions whenever I can, as a practice. However I can't seem to find my way out of this requirement without a trigger.

```
create table item ( title varchar2(32) primary key );
create table price ( 
   item           varchar2(32) not null references item (title), 
   price          number(9,2), 
   effective_from date not null, 
   effective_to   date not null, 
   constraint price_from_to_ck check (effective_to > effective_from ));

[REDACTED]
*(A combination of row and statement level triggers inteneded to prevent logical chronological overlap)

insert into item values ('LETTUCE');
insert into item values ('WHISKY');

insert into price values ( 'LETTUCE', 1.05, date '2013-01-01', date '2013-03-31' );
insert into price values ( 'LETTUCE', 1.08, date '2013-04-01', date '2013-06-30' ); 
insert into price values ( 'WHISKY', 33.99, date '2013-01-01', date '2013-05-31' );
insert into price values ( 'WHISKY', 31.15, date '2013-06-01', date '2013-07-31' ); 

-- should fail
insert into price values ( 'WHISKY', 30.55, date '2013-05-15', date '2013-06-05' );
```

Comment: It is difficult to *correctly* enforce this kind of "non-overlapping" constraint using triggers.  You need some form of locking because you can't "see" changes that other sessions are making, and they might conflict with yours.  See [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:474221407101) and [here](http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/08/30/non-overlapping-dates-constraint/) for some discussion.  Other approaches to consider might be: a) store only the "from" date and assume that each row is valid until the next "from" date, or, b) use a materialized view.

Comment: @BrianCamire The first link to AskTom is a procedural solution. And, I guess I don't see yours or the Jeff Kemp article's point that this is a multi-user concurrency issue at heart. This has the same aspects of concurrency as a not null constraint. I am concerned only that a single transaction does not violate the constraint.

Comment: I disagree.  A procedure solution is an option (although you still need locking), but the AskTom link discusses mostly trigger-based approaches.  Concurrency is more of an issue than a not null constraint, because: a) a not null constrant can be enforced declaratively, and, b) a not null constraint applies only to one row at a time.  To illustrate the concurreny issue, the solution you posted will not prevent two concurrent transactions from inserting identical (and therefore overlapping) rows at the same time.

Comment: Two rows cannot be inserted at the same time. And the example I have in the question (presuming a typical READ COMMITTED transaction) would not allow the second insert. But yes, it is different than a not null constraint. What I want in the end is behavior on such a constraint that is very much handled like a not null constraint.

Comment: The solution you posted would allow a concurrent insert of overlapping rows.  Try this in two SQL*Plus sessions, say named A and B:  a) in Session A, insert a row, b) in Session B, insert a row with overlapping values, c) in Session A, commit the transaction, and, d) in Session B, commit the transaction.  You now have an overlap.

Comment: @BrianCamire Yes you are right. And the silly thing is that I knew you were right from the jump. It gets at the heart of wanting a declarative solution rather than a procedural one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While waiting for next Oracle 12c version, which supports [Temporal Validity](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17620/adfns_design.htm#ADFNS967), I still use next approach:

```
create table item ( title varchar2(32) primary key );
create table price ( 
   price_id          number primary key,
   item              varchar2(32) not null references item (title), 
   price             number(9,2), 
   effective_from    date not null, 
   effective_to      date not null, 
   effective_prev_to date,
   constraint price_from_to_ck check ( effective_to > effective_from ),
   constraint price_to_prev_ck check ( effective_from = effective_prev_to + 1 ),
   constraint price_from_uq unique ( item, effective_to ),
   constraint price_dates_chain_fk foreign key ( item, effective_prev_to ) references price ( item, effective_to ) );

insert into item values ('LETTUCE');
insert into item values ('WHISKY');

insert into price values ( 1, 'LETTUCE', 1.05, date '2013-01-01', date '2013-03-31', null );
insert into price values ( 2, 'LETTUCE', 1.08, date '2013-04-01', date '2013-06-30', date '2013-03-31' ); 
insert into price values ( 3, 'WHISKY', 33.99, date '2013-01-01', date '2013-05-31', null );
insert into price values ( 4, 'WHISKY', 31.15, date '2013-06-01', date '2013-07-31', date '2013-05-31' );
```

Let's [try](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7df1/1):

```
insert into price values ( 5, 'WHISKY', 30.55, date '2013-05-15', date '2013-06-05', date '2013-05-14' ); 

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (USER_4_E7DF1.PRICE_DATES_CHAIN_FK) violated - parent key not found : insert into price values ( 'WHISKY', 30.55, date '2013-05-15', date '2013-06-05', date '2013-05-14' )
```

But now updating and deleting dates in the middle of the chain is pain in the ass. It needs to change preceding and following rows in one statement with `MERGE`. That's why I've added `price_id` column, because you can't update a key in `MERGE` -- so, you need another key instead of (item, effective_%).

Comment: +1 for the 12c link. I'm taking a look at that possibility. The 12c concept of a "PERIOD" is very much the direction I want to go. I think it is entirely possible I could piece together something similar. Let me tinker and post what I come up with (for those of us in 11g for the foreseeable future).

Comment: My tinkering keeps leading me back to triggers. (sigh). This is far better a solution than a trigger in my opinion. And it isn't too cryptic. Also, wrapping a DAL around MERGE statements seems elegant enough. Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI. Solution you provided in your question has two major lacks. First, **it doesn't work in concurrent environment**: one session see no changes that other sessions do until they commit it. Second, **it doesn't work immediatly**: when you _already_ have a broken data you need to insert something to make trigger to fire. Third, **it doesn't works at all**: you forgot to eliminate a row from `p` in subquery to `p2`, so you can insert just one row into the `price` table, then it will join to itself in `exists` part.

Comment: The trigger source was definitely concurrent failure (Brian finally got that through my thick skull) and actual code was not intended/tested as useful - just instructive on the general approach, so no worries.

Comment: It seems it would be nearly equivalent and simpler (with two fewer columns, no foreign key constraint, and no special update considerations) to store only `effective_from` (with a unique constraint on it with `item`).  One logical difference, though, would be that the "last" row would not be end-dated -- it would remain effective until a "later" row was created.

Comment: @CleverIdeaWidgetry , please, note in your question that the code is just a sample and not a working solution. Save some newbie programmer's head.

Comment: Using the implicit values could reduce components of the equation but for a variety of reasons creates other headaches for me.

Comment: @Brian Without those two columns and related constraints it's not so simple task to query a row on a certain date. You gain something (simplicity in DML), you lose something (simplicity in querying).

Comment: Agreed, @suPPLer.  Still, there are some ways to partly make up for this, like using a view to calculate the end date (maybe using the `LEAD` analytic function), and then querying the view instead of table (although maybe with a performance impact).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this declaritively with a materialized view, as first suggested by Brian Camire.  Here's an example:

```
--Original tables (with an extra primary key on PRICE)
create table item ( title varchar2(32) primary key );
create table price ( 
   id             number primary key,
   item           varchar2(32) not null references item (title), 
   price          number(9,2), 
   effective_from date not null, 
   effective_to   date not null, 
   constraint price_from_to_ck check (effective_to > effective_from ));

create materialized view log on price with rowid;

--Items with overlapping dates
create materialized view price_no_overlap_mv
refresh fast on commit as
select 'overlapping row' as dummy, price1.rowid rowid1, price2.rowid rowid2
from price price1, price price2
where
    --Same item
    price1.item = price2.item
    --Overlapping dates
    and (price1.effective_from <= price2.effective_to and price1.effective_to >= price2.effective_from) 
    --Don't compare the same row
    and price1.id <> price2.id
;

--Throw an error if any rows ever get created.
alter table price_no_overlap_mv
add constraint price_no_overlap_mv_ck check (dummy = 'no rows allowed');


insert into item values ('LETTUCE');
insert into item values ('WHISKY');

insert into price values (1, 'LETTUCE', 1.05, date '2013-01-01', date '2013-03-31' );
insert into price values (2, 'LETTUCE', 1.08, date '2013-04-01', date '2013-06-30' ); 
insert into price values (3, 'WHISKY', 33.99, date '2013-01-01', date '2013-05-31' );
insert into price values (4, 'WHISKY', 31.15, date '2013-06-01', date '2013-07-31' ); 
commit;

-- should fail
insert into price values (5, 'WHISKY', 30.55, date '2013-05-15', date '2013-06-05' ); 
commit;
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (JHELLER.PRICE_NO_OVERLAP_MV_CK) violated
```

This declarative approach is both concurrent and consistent.  But there are a lot of draw backs:

1. Materialized view logs, which are required for a fast refresh, are only supported in Enterprise Edition.
2. Your table needs a primary key, although you probably already have one but just didn't include it in the example.
3. Although declarative, the solution is still not straight-forward.  You have to declare the *opposite* condition, and then check that it never exists.
4. Getting `FAST REFRESH` to work can be a nightmare for more than the simplest of queries.  Even for this simple example, I had to use the old-style joins and had to add useless ROWIDs.
5. The constraint is not enforced until a `COMMIT`.  Although that could be a positive thing, as many types of changes would temporarily create overlapping results.  If you *never* allow overlapping results, you have to modify the table in a specific order.

Comment: This is an approach I have used in the past and it is not intuitive enough to maintain in the world I live in.