# Oracle - Intervals timestamp

Tags: oracle, datetime, intervals

What is the best practice to manage time intervals in Oracle? For example: I have a room that will be rented between 8:15 till 9:00. So I have at least 2 fields: dt_start and dt_end, I suppose. I can not permit to enter a rent between 8:45 till 9:20. So how would be the best table structure for that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear consensus on the best way to implement this.  The answer certainly depends a great deal on your exact situation.  The options are:

1. **Table with unique constraint on ROOM_ID and a block of time.**  This is only realistic if the application allocates a reasonably small amount of time using reasonably large blocks.  For example, if a room can only be allocated for at most a week, 5 minutes at a time.  But if reservations are to the second, and can span over a year, this would require 31 million rows for one reservation.
2. **Trigger.**  Avoid this solution if possible.  The chance of implementing this logic in a trigger that is both consistent and concurrent is very low.
3. **Materialized view.**  This is my preferred approach.  For example, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17708601/409172).
4. **Enforced by the application.**  This only works if the application can serialize access and if no ad hoc SQL is allowed.
5. **Commercial Tool.**  For example, [RuleGen](http://www.rulegen.com/).

Comment: +1 except for #4 - unless the application implements some sort of serialization. c.f. http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/08/30/non-overlapping-dates-constraint/

Answer (score 0):

[**BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER**](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php) is the best way to accomplish your need.

In trigger, figure out that the new time is not conflicting the current time of your particular room, and if so you can `Rais Error`, otherwise let the update happen.

Comment: Won't work as soon as you have two sessions trying to book the same room.