# Is it possible to create a function based unique index to prevent overlaps in ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 11g database
I have a table with a 4 value composite key which also has 3 numeric ranges and 1 date range (8 fields)  The composite key must be unique but I also need to allow insert if one or more of the 4 ranges do not overlap but prevent insert if all 4 ranges have overlaps.   Can this be done with a function based unique index?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by overlapping? Could you share your table's structure and an example of legal and illegal data so we can see the difference?

Comment: One range would be minBalance & maxBalance.  One row could have 0-1000 and another 1000 to 2000 and that would not be an overlap.  Same with the other 3 ranges.   An overlap would be 0-1000 and 500-1500.   I need to allow overlaps but not in all 4 ranges at the same time.  I need to query on the table giving values that are within each range but It must not return more than one matching row that meets any set of criteria.

Comment: @Mureinik: Don is looking for something like this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT but that is not available in Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For a function based unique index to work, you need to establish an equivalence relation. Range overlaps are not equivalence relations.

Comment: So how can I add data validation at the database level.   The only way i can think is to add an insert trigger that runs a query to check for conflicting range overlaps with the row being inserted.

Comment: Yes, an insert trigger is the only way to do this.

Comment: @Don Another method is to use a materialized view.  I've created an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17708601/409172).